# Wordpress theme internationnalisation

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I just created my own theme so that I could developpe wordpress site faster. But now I got to make it multi-lang. Here is what I have done until now.

1 : I changed all the text in my theme for : _e("my_text","my_theme") and __("my_text","my_theme")

2 : I generated .po and .mo file with poedit (autogenerated base on key-word and relative path) (named my_theme_fr_FR.po and my_theme_fr_FR.mo)

3 : I made all the traduction I needed and saved the file back

4 : I saved them in my languages folder (in my theme)

5 : I uploaded all my theme to be sure

6 : I verify by ftp that all the files were there

7 : I add a hook in functions.php

```
function custom_theme_setup() {
    load_theme_textdomain("my_theme", get_template_directory()."/languages/");
} // end custom_theme_setup
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_setup');
```

In theory my theme is supposed to be ready, but when I tried to execute it (even if I change the WPLANG to fr_FR in wp-config.php) everything is still in english. The admin of wp changed to fr_FR (because I got the .mo) but the text in the front end is still in english...

I followed the tutorial : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/translating-your-theme--wp-25014
but still nothing work...

I'm wondering what I did wrong...
Any help would be great.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The languages files (.mo) must be written my_theme-fr_FR.mo not my_theme_fr_FR.mo (notice the '-')

Plus, they must be in the directory wp-content/languages/themes/ not in wp-content/themes/my_theme/languages/

Hope this help someone